# Simplest driver with visual studio wdk

Tags: visual-studio-2012, driver, wdk

I'm trying to create a simplest "hello world" driver in Visual Studio 2012 with WDK.
The code of Device.c file is this:

`#include <ntddk.h>`

```
NTSTATUS DriverEntry(PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath)
{
    DbgPrint("Hello, World");

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

When building there's an error:

```
1>Driver.c(3): error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
1>Driver.c(3): warning C4100: 'RegistryPath' : unreferenced formal parameter
1>Driver.c(3): warning C4100: 'DriverObject' : unreferenced formal parameter
2>------ Build started: Project: KMDFSmall Package, Configuration: Win7 Debug x64 ------
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\build\WindowsDriver8.0.common.targets(1347,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "Path\To\Projects\SimpleDriver\x64\Win7Debug\KMDFSmall.sys" because it was not found.
```

What causes these errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The WDK has "Treat warning as error" activated, and unused parameters trigger a warning.

So if you change your code to :

```
NTSTATUS DriverEntry(PDRIVER_OBJECT /*DriverObject*/, PUNICODE_STRING /*RegistryPath*/)
{
    DbgPrint("Hello, World");

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

it should compile.

Comment: you are right, I just set Treat warning as error to NO and it's ok

Answer (score 7):

More recommended way is using `UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER()` macro, so your function can be changed to:

```
NTSTATUS DriverEntry(PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(DriverObject);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(RegistryPath);

    DbgPrint("Hello, World");

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A shorter way to do t is by using IN:

```
#include <ntddk.h>

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT theDriverObject, IN PUNICODE_STRING theRegistryPath) {
    DbgPrint("Hello World!\n");
    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

Source: Subverting the Windows Kernel: Rootkits by Greg Hoglund & James Butler